# Using an Xpath expression to check xml elements that refer to other elements

Tags: xml, xpath, referential-integrity

Imagine I have an XML structure:

```
<root>
    <products>
        <product>
            <name>myproduct 1</name>
        </product>
        <product>
            <name>myproduct 2</name>
        </product>
    </products>
    <invoices>
        <invoice number="1">
            <product>myproduct 1</product>
        </invoice>
        <invoice number="2">
            <product>myproduct 3</product>
        </invoice>
    </invoices>
</root>
```

I need an XPath expression to locate only the invoice elements for which product element exists (so product in invoice matches the name of product). So in this case it would find invoice 1, but not invoice 2.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is possible :

```
//invoice[product = /root/products/product/name]
```

or :

```
//invoice[product = //products/product/name]
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/6fe85af65ce9cf2990114187031c1d87)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<invoice number="1"> 
  <product>myproduct 1</product> 
</invoice>
```

Comment: Thanks - let me check that out.

Comment: Great. It also worked with a not condition to remove invalid entries.